# Cannot retrieve BundleContext in a web application

Tags: osgi, war

I have added the following bundles to can deploy a war (web application) into an OSGi framework.I use the "Apache Felix distribuable binary" :

```
   32|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Logging - API (1.7.0)
   33|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Logging - Service (1.7.1.SNAPSHOT)
   34|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Url - mvn: (1.3.5)
   35|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Url - war (1.3.5)
   36|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Url - wrap: (1.3.5)
   37|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - API (1.1.12)
   38|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - FileInstall Deployer (1.1.12)
   39|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - Extender - WAR (1.1.12)
   40|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - Extender - Whiteboard (1.1.12)
   41|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - Jetty Bundle (1.1.12)
   42|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - Jsp Support (1.1.12)
   43|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - Runtime (1.1.12)
   44|Active     |   20|OPS4J Pax Web - Service SPI (1.1.12)
```

So, I used a simple struts 2 application (Hello world) for test, I created the war and then I put it in the "file install" directory, and It became active, and I can see my welcome page.
After this, I tried to retrieve the BundleContext to can use the registered services from the war, I have added:

```
BundleContext ctx = (BundleContext) ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("osgi-bundlecontext");
```

But, I found the exception:

"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl cannot be cast to org.osgi.framework.BundleContext"

What can be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I see this message in th LOG:    
[WebListenerExecutor: 1] DEBUG org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - org/osgi/service/web/DEPLOYED
PackageAdmin service is unavailable.

Comment: Is it possible that you added osgi-core to the bundles and the org.osgi.framework.BundleContext class exists twice in your OSGi container? Ones it comes from the container and ones from the jar file. The PAX module wires to the framework while your wab wires to the osgi-core.jar

Comment: Thank you for the response,  yes, it appears this is the problem, the generated jar bundle from the simple war embeds all the war dependencies in the jar and add them to the bundle classpath (Bundle-ClassPath:: ...., WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.core-5.0.0.jar).
I don't know for the moment how can I manage this manifest file to avoid this, if I try with the bundle maven pluggin to generate a bundle instead of the war, I can't have the same correct jar packaging

Comment: You can set the scope to provided for that dependency in your pom.xml than it will not be included in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Made a real answer from comments (as till now my comments were only guesses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an answer from discussion in comments:

You have the mentioned class twice in the classpath. Ones it exists in the OSGi container and ones it is included in a jar file. The PAX modules import the class from the OSGi container while your webapp imports it from the external jar file.

In your case the jar is included in WEB-INF/lib. As you are using Maven you should set the scope of osgi-core dependency to provided.

Comment: Until this, it is perfect, but I should also add an import of this package instead of using it from the local class-path, because with this solution I have a new InvocationTargetException (org.osgi.framework.BundleContext not found). So how can I do this (adding an import to the generated bundle manifest). Thanks :)

Comment: Does exist a plugin like "maven bundle plugin" to generate a wab bundle (enabling me to manage the list of import/export package inside a web project ) ?

Comment: maven-bundle-plugin can generate wab project. In the instructions you can define Web-ContextPath, _wab-  I think you can find about a detailed doc in google easily.